# WCF data service no refresh changes from database updates

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I am having a problem while trying to refresh data in a Gridview, the thing is if I have my app running and I update something on the database the new data is not refreshed but if I close the app and rerun again the changes appear.

Here is my piece of code in the constructor:

```
IQueryable<GyLoadCarrier> loadCarrierQuery = queryRepository.GetGyLoadCarriers();

        LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader = new WcsDomainCollectionViewLoader<GyLoadCarrier>(loadCarrierQuery)
        {
            RequestTotalItemCount = true
        };

        LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader.LoadStarted += OnLoadCarrierMfsTransportsLoaderLoadStarted;
        LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader.LoadCompleted +=OnLoadCarrierMfsTransportsLoaderLoadCompleted;

        AvailableLoadCarriers = new DomainCollectionView<GyLoadCarrier>(LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader,
                                                                        LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader.Data);
        LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader.View = AvailableLoadCarriers;

        INotifyCollectionChanged notifyingSortLoadCarrierDestination = AvailableLoadCarriers.SortDescriptions;
        notifyingSortLoadCarrierDestination.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => AvailableLoadCarriers.MoveToFirstPage();

        using (AvailableLoadCarriers.DeferRefresh())
        {
            AvailableLoadCarriers.PageSize = 30;
            AvailableLoadCarriers.MoveToFirstPage();
        }
```

LoadCarriersMfsTransportsLoader.Load("LoadCarrierAddressChanged");

And the the refresh command is just:

```
 protected override void OnRefresh()
    {

        MfsTransportsLoader.Load(Resources.Strings.LoadingMfsTransportsProgressMessage);
    }
```

So any idea why is this happening??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that from your client you run the same query twice (before and after the update) using the same instance of DataServiceContext (or derived) class, this is very likely due to MergeOption (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.mergeoption.aspx). The default value which is AppendOnly prevents the updates to be applied to your client side objects because they already exist (this is to not overwrite any potential changes you may have made). You can probably fix this by setting the DataServiceContext.MergeOption to OverwriteChanges.